# Form as a class jinja2

Tags: google-app-engine, wtforms

I'm using WTForm with Google App Engine.  I want to access my form as a class.

this works with djangoforms...

```
class PostForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = BlogPost
    exclude = [ 'path', 'published', 'updated' ]
```

How do I do the equivalent with WTforms.

```
class PostForm(model_form):
  class Meta:
    model = BlogPost
    exclude = [ 'path', 'published', 'updated' ]
```

I get this error with traceback...

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 225, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1858, in load_module
    return self.FindAndLoadModule(submodule, fullname, search_path)
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1722, in FindAndLoadModule
    description)
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 676, in Decorate
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver_import_hook.py", line 1665, in LoadModuleRestricted
    description)
  File "C:\Users\John\webdev\gae-projects\cmwo-blog\admin.py", line 69, in <module>
    class PostForm(model_form):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    function() argument 1 must be code, not str
INFO     2012-07-30 14:40:31,700 dev_appserver.py:2952] "GET /admin/newpost HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: looks like something went wrong with model_form, maybe you override it by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model_form of WTForms doesn't take care of any Meta inner class. Maybe you can override the `'__init__'` method of your PostForm class.

Comment: Yes, appears this isn't supported in WTForms like it is in Djangoforms.